# WebView React Native Authorization Issue

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, webview, authorization

Given the webview below, innerHTML is a string which contains an image (`<img src = ../>`). The image is not rendered due to a **401 error** (unauthorized). The webview is not authorized to get the image. How do I pass the authorization token along with the webview such that it renders the html image correctly? I tried injecting a cookie containing the token as JS code, but it did not recognize the token.
Moreover, given that this is an html source (not a uri), I am unable to pass headers along with the html.

```
      <WebView
        .....
        source={{
          html: innerHTML
          baseUrl,
      }}
         .....
/>
```

Thank you!